# how to change virtue mart feature products display layout

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

am very new to joomla,now am doing project on joomla.i want to change featured products display formate/layout.Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of places that they appear, including the Component and Modules, but the best place to start looking is in the various Views folders within  `components\com_virtuemart\views`.  From there, I often find a piece of text that is appearing on the page, and further search for that within all the VM files to see where else it might be "dragged in" from.